# Boolean equivalent of pandas to_numeric()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, etl, petl

I am searching for the boolean equivalent of pandas to_numeric()
I want the function to convert a column to True/False/nan if at all possible, and if not throw an error.

My motivation is that I need to auto recognize and convert boolean columns in a dataset with ~1000 columns.  I can do a similar things with floats/integers using the following code:

```
df = df_raw.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='ignore')
```

Comment: Are you wanting to convert strings that look like `'True'` and `'False'` to `True` and `False` then determine if that entire column is nothing but `True` and `False`?

Answer (score 6):

Since `pd.to_numeric` is primarily used to convert strings to numeric values, I'm going to work under the assumption that you want to convert strings of literal boolean values.

Consider the dataframe `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
        ['1', None, 'True'],
        ['False', 2, True]
    ])

print(df)

       0    1     2
0      1  NaN  True
1  False  2.0  True
```

***My Choice***
*This is what I'd propose. Further below, I break it down in an attempt to explain what is going on.*

```
def try_eval2(x):
    if type(x) is str:
        try:
            x = literal_eval(x)
        except:
            x = np.nan

    if type(x) is not bool:
        x = np.nan

    return x

vals = df.values
v = vals.ravel()
a = np.array([try_eval2(x) for x in v.tolist()], dtype=object)
pd.DataFrame(a.reshape(vals.shape), df.index, df.columns)

       0    1     2
0    NaN  NaN  True
1  False  NaN  True
```

---

***Timing***
*You'll notice that my proposed solution is pretty fast*

```
%%timeit
vals = df.values
v = vals.ravel()
a = np.array([try_eval2(x) for x in v.tolist()], dtype=object)
pd.DataFrame(a.reshape(vals.shape), df.index, df.columns)
10000 loops, best of 3: 149 µs per loop

%timeit df.astype(str).applymap(to_boolean)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.28 ms per loop

%timeit df.astype(str).stack().map({'True':True, 'False':False}).unstack()
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.27 ms per loop
```

---

## Explanation

***Step 1***
*Now I'll create a simple function using `ast.literal_eval` to convert strings to values*

```
from ast import literal_eval

def try_eval(x):
    try:
        x = literal_eval(x)
    except:
        pass
    return x
```

***Step 2***
*`applymap` with my new function.  It's going to look the same!*

```
d1 = df.applymap(try_eval)
print(d1)

       0    1     2
0      1  NaN  True
1  False  2.0  True
```

***Step 3***
*Use `where` and `applymap` again to find where values are actually `bool`*

```
d2 = d1.where(d1.applymap(type).eq(bool))
print(d2)

       0   1     2
0    NaN NaN  True
1  False NaN  True
```

***Step 4***
*You can drop columns with all `NaN`*

```
print(d2.dropna(1, 'all'))

       0     2
0    NaN  True
1  False  True
```

Comment: I think I checked this later and found that they approach equivalent timing.  I'll try to circle back and show it.

Answer (score 5):

You need [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) with [`where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) where replace to `NaN` all not `boolean`:

```
df = df.replace({'True':True,'False':False})
df = df.where(df.applymap(type) == bool)
```

Old solution (very slow):

You can [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) to strings if some boolean in `df`, [`applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) with custom function and [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast-helpers) for converting:

```
from ast import literal_eval

def to_boolean(x):
    try:
        x = literal_eval(x)
        if type(x) == bool:
            return x
        else:
            return np.nan
    except:
        x = np.nan
    return x

print (df.astype(str).applymap(to_boolean))
#with borrowing sample from piRSquared
       0   1     2
0    NaN NaN  True
1  False NaN  True
```

**Timings**:

```
In [76]: %timeit (jez(df))
1 loop, best of 3: 488 ms per loop

In [77]: %timeit (jez2(df))
1 loop, best of 3: 527 ms per loop

#piRSquared fastest solution
In [78]: %timeit (pir(df))
1 loop, best of 3: 5.42 s per loop

#maxu solution
In [79]: %timeit df.astype(str).stack().map({'True':True, 'False':False}).unstack()
1 loop, best of 3: 1.88 s per loop

#jezrael ols solution
In [80]: %timeit df.astype(str).applymap(to_boolean)
1 loop, best of 3: 13.3 s per loop
```

**Code for timings**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
        ['True', False, '1', 0, None, 5.2],
        ['False', True, '0', 1, 's', np.nan]])

#[20000 rows x 60 columns]
df = pd.concat([df]*10000).reset_index(drop=True)
df = pd.concat([df]*10, axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)
df.columns = pd.RangeIndex(len(df.columns))
#print (df)
```

---

```
def to_boolean(x):
    try:
        x = literal_eval(x)
        if type(x) == bool:
            return x
        else:
            return np.nan
    except:
        x = np.nan
    return x


def try_eval2(x):
    if type(x) is str:
        try:
            x = literal_eval(x)
        except:
            x = np.nan

    if type(x) is not bool:
        x = np.nan

    return x
```

---

```
def pir(df):
    vals = df.values
    v = vals.ravel()
    a = np.array([try_eval2(x) for x in v.tolist()], dtype=object)
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(a.reshape(vals.shape), df.index, df.columns)
    return (df2)

def jez(df):
    df = df.replace({'True':True,'False':False})
    df = df.where(df.applymap(type) == bool)
    return (df)

def jez2(df):
    df = df.replace({'True':True,'False':False})
    df = df.where(df.applymap(type).eq(bool))
    return (df)
```

Answer (score 3):

`astype` is a more specific version of `pd.to_numeric`:

```
df = df_raw.astype('bool')
```

Comment: This is what I was thinking... However, `bool(3.14)` is `True`... Is that what OP wanted?  I'm not sure.  Plus One because you rock and this is useful.

Comment: Yeah, I think I didn't read the question carefully. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 3):

I used @piRSquared's sample DF:

```
In [39]: df
Out[39]:
       0    1     2
0      1  NaN  True
1  False  2.0  True

In [40]: df.astype(str).stack().map({'True':True, 'False':False}).unstack()
Out[40]:
       0    1     2
0    NaN  NaN  True
1  False  NaN  True
```